# Mapping of custom exception in JAX-RS via @WebFault annotation

Tags: java, json, cxf, jax-rs

I am developing a Client-Server app with **JAX-RS** / Apache **CXF**, **JSON**

I would like **Apache CXF** to handle my exception transparently on both ends : Which means transforming the exception into a bean, serializing it with my Jackson Serializer (JSON) and then doing the over way around on client side.

I have seen several confusing posts/answers on this subject and came up with using the @WebFault annotation :

```
@WebFault(name=CODE, faultBean="foo.bar.FaultBean")
public class DuplicateRuleNameFault extends Exception {
   static final public String CODE = "DUPLICATE_RULE_NAME";
   private FaultBean faultBean;

   public DuplicateRuleNameFault(String msg) {
     super(msg);
     this.faultBean = new FaultBean(msg);
   }
   public DuplicateRuleNameFault() {
   }
   public FaultBean getFaultBean() {
     return faultBean;
   }
   public void setFaultBean(FaultBean faultBean) {
     this.faultBean = faultBean;
   }
}
```

With no success ... Currently, CXF seems to happily ignore the annotation on the Exception and handle it as an unknown exception : 500 status error and no response body generated on the server side.

Is there something specific I have to configure in the "" server element of my Spring context ? I already have Spring scanning my Exception/FaultBean classes (is it even needed BTW ?).

I would appreciate if you could point me at some working example.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please share how you did the solution... i am facing the same issue :(

Comment: We have switched to "functional exception" :
We have an exception mapper on cserver side that builds custom JSON upon an exception.

Then, on client side, I use an inInterceptor to unmarshal JSON and throw an exception is it correponds to an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@WebFault's` are not part of the JAX-RS specification. You will want to read up on [section 3.3.4](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/jaxrs-1.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1358782516_4879766fc9a794baaee165542f4097d5) of the specification, which describes the different ways you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

***Option 1***

Design your resource classes to throw [WebApplicationException's](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html). Set the `response` property of these exceptions to be a valid JAX-RS response containing the fault beans you want to send to the client.

***Option 2***

Define exception mapping providers. You can create a hierarchy of these to handle all the common exceptions your application will throw. Or you can create a top level exception with an embedded bean and an exception handler for it. And then derive several specific exceptions from the top level one.

```
public abstract class MyApplicationException<T> extends Exception {
    private T faultBean;

    // Constructors, setters/getters
}

@Provider
public class MyApplicationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<MyApplicationException<?>> {
    // Implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I ifnally did it like that, with one ExceptionMaopper on SS and one ResponseExceptionMapper on the client.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is by using the javax.ws.rs.core.Response object like so :

@GET

@Path("/")

public Response getBlah()

{

```
try {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity(<Object you want to return>).build();
}
catch (final DuplicateRuleNameFault e) {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
            .entity(e.getFaultBean().getMsg()).build();
}
```

}

Comment: Sure, but this way I will also have to handle the parsing of the Exception by hand on the client side.
I would like to take the benefit of JAX-RS and CXF wihch allows to instantiate client dynamically by wrapping around a service definition, within a single line of code.